# how to save a generated output of integers to a txt file via python

Tags: python-3.x

I have written code to generate numbers from 0500000000 to 0500000100:

```
def generator(nums):
    count = 0
    while count < 100:
        gg=print('05',count, sep='')
        count += 1  
g = generator(10)
```

as I use linux, I thought I may be able to use this command `python pythonfilename.py >> file.txt`

Yet, I get an error.

So, before `g = generator(10)` I added:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(gg)
    f.close()
```

but I got an error:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Any solution?

Comment: See my answer. Are you trying to make gg = "05"+str(count)

Comment: Try solution 1 in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument needs to be a `str`, make it one:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(gg))
    f.close()
```

But the real problem (as @ruler-of-the-world says) is that you define `gg` to the result of `print`; `print` does not have a real result, it returns `None`. You probably instead want to assign `gg` as:

```
gg = '05' + str(count)
```

---

But with all that said, what was the error that prevented you from using `print` and `python pythonfilename.py >> file.txt`?

If I create the following file as `printy.py`:

```
def generator(nums):
    count = 0
    while count < 100:
        print('05', count, sep='')
        count += 1

g = generator(10)
```

And in terminal run:

```
python3 printy.py >> file.txt
```

Then I get a nice `file.txt` file containing a hundred lines of numbers.

Comment: It worked in terminal now. I forgot to specify the version of python. Obviously, I got a syntax error in my previous try.

Comment: Thanks for including me in your answer Krildo, not many people bother to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

## The error:

When you use `gg=print()` you are setting gg to `None`.

This is then causing an error because gg is not a string, it is none.

#### Solution 1

If you want gg to equal `05, count` use `gg = "05" + str(count)`

You will then have to print the results separately.

#### Solution 2

If you want gg to equal `"print('05',count, sep='')"` (write that to file) then put speech marks around the print

Comment: with the first solution I get only the last number of the generated numbers 0599.

the second one literally outputs "print('05',count, sep='')" which can be fixed through an extended solution.

Comment: @AlJumaia If you want more zeros before the 99, change `gg = "05" + str(count)` to `gg = "05000000" + str(count)` or as many 0's as you want